# Using Eclipse, TabLayout error on layout.xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

As it is shown there, I have imported the android-support-design.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar libraries without source. Although including android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar into layout.xml file does not make any error, including android.support.design.widget.TabLayout makes an error as like:

The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.design.widget.TabLayout

However, I can declare TabLayout object into the MainActivity. The MainActivity accepts the design library, but layout.xml file does not.
How can I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Just for note.  I suggest moving to Android Studio.  It is the official Android IDE. Make your life a lot easier.

Comment: @Vitiello try restarting your eclipse please.

Answer (score 1):

Try `clean` > `Build project`

or restarting `Eclipse` problably you have cache issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your advices. I decided to re-install SDK and moved into Android Studio. Despite of a little bit slowness compered to Eclipse, everything works properly. Sorry for those who searched the same error and found this unsolved question. I recommend the same way that I have followed.